# Practical example of MVVM for Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Ever since I began learning about `Xamarin.Forms`, I've read that `MVVM` is the preferred architecture for this. This is all new to me, so please be patient.

At work, a typical application (either asp.net or Windows Forms) will include an event handler that calls a method and displays it into a UI control:

```
private void buttonShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Vendors.Sales carSales = new Vendors.Sales();
    DataTable carsTable = carSales.SalesMade();
    DatagridSales.datasource = carsTable;
}
```

`carSales.SalesMade` is a method that exists somewhere that returns a list that I display in my UI. I don't know what `carSales.SalesMade` is; I just know it returns a `datatable`.

This exact same *idea* is what I want to apply to my *beginner's* mobile app. The problem is that I haven't found a simple working example that implements MVVM to this very simple functionality that I want to accomplish. Most of the examples I've found are so convoluted that they confuse more than they help.

So my question is: how can I implement MVVM in this example? It can be pseudocode; it doesn't need to build/compile. I just want to see what it would look like.

Answer (score 2):

So just to elaborate on Commands and how they work.

Take a simple login button example.

Your ViewModel will have a Command to handle the login button click like so:

```
public ICommand LoginCommand {get; set;};
```

The command needs an action to call when the command is fired.

So in your constructor, you could initialize the command with the following :

```
LoginCommand = new Command(Login);
```

The Login Action corresponds to a method you have in your ViewModel like so:

```
private void Login()
{
   //do login stuff
}
```

Finally, in your View you Bind the command to your control in this case the login button:

```
 <Button x:Name="loginButton" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" Text="Login" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that using event handlers is something that you shouldn't do in MVVM. You should bind the `Command` to the button in this particular case.

Comment: I understand that. That's why I was looking at a simple-enough example that would implement something like this.